# How can I find repeat word in word?

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

I have try the wildcard: Step [a-zA-Z0-9’]{1,}([, ~to-]{1,}[a-zA-Z0-9’]{1,})

It can only search all item except the last one and First one.

Is there a wildcard can search all of below item?

```
Step 50
Step 200-250
Step 200 - 250
Step 200~250
Step 200 to 250
Step 200,210,220.... (repeat)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve, exactly? Do you need any capturing groups? The regex should match the entire string, or one match per line is fine?

Comment: I have a table that record like .. Step 200,210,220,230,240,250,260 that I have to check the word "Step 200 - 250" that 200 and 250 is in the Step

Comment: You have this tagged as [regex], but from your comments to the answers already provided it sounds like you don't want to use `Regex`, just `Find`.  Is that correct?  If so, it may be best to remove the [regex] tag.  (And also tag it as [ms-word] instead of [word] - the [word] tag says "*Important: This is NOT about Microsoft Word or text editing* A word is the amount of data that a processor can fit in its general-purpose registers -- effectively the amount of data the processor can handle "at once".)

Comment: @YowE3K The tag [regex] is add by MartinSmith,Thanks your kindnest,I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Step ([0-9]+(\s?([-~,]|to)\s?)?)+
```

Comment: [Find Target] contains an invalid [mode match search]

Answer (score 0):

treat your items like that

```
Step[space]([number][separator][number])
```

the separator will be `-`,`~`,`to` or `,` with some space. 
and the part in brackets can be repeated.
so i got the regexp like that

```
Step\s*(([\s-~,]|to)*\d+)*
```

Comment: do you mean microsoft word ? how about using a text editor tool like vscode? it's more efficient.

Comment: sorry, i cant use other tool.

Comment: @鄭有維 note that the [`word` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/word/info) that you used in the question doesn't refer to MS Word.

Comment: Thanks your note~